# Swift storing dictionary in array

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi all I'm new to swift and I'm getting a error when trying to store dictionary's into an array

When running the code in playground it works fine but when I place the code into my Model class I get a error "Instance member 'album1' cannot be used on type 'Model'"

```
let album1:[String:String] = ["artist":"michael jackson", "title":"thriller"]
let album2:[String:String] = ["artist":"linkin park", "title":"hybrid theory"]
let album3:[String:String] = ["artist":"of monsters and men", "title":"beneath the skin"]

var albums = [album1,album2,album3]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what type of error are you getting?

Comment: What's the code for your Model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare array property without using other properties

```
var albums = [[String:String]]()
```

and move it initialization code to some `init` method of your class

```
init() {
    albums = [album1,album2,album3]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this code to viewDidLoad and did not get any error messages, perhaps you need to move it to some type of initializing method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    let album1:[String:String] = ["artist":"michael jackson", "title":"thriller"]
    let album2:[String:String] = ["artist":"linkin park", "title":"hybrid theory"]
    let album3:[String:String] = ["artist":"of monsters and men", "title":"beneath the skin"]

    let albums = [album1,album2,album3]

    print(albums)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create struct and store there your data. Example:

```
struct Album {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let artist: String
    let title: String

    // MARK: - Lifecicle

    init(withArtist artist: String, andTitle title: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Next you can use this as an example:

```
let album1 = Album(withArtist: "MJ", andTitle: "Thriller")
...

let albums: [Album] = [album1, ...]
```

It's less error-prone than using string literals in dictionaries.

Comment: You not solved problem. You suggested other data structure (that not asked) and your example written in OP environment will result same error.